# Java - Formatting Double data types, getting error

Tags: java, format, printf

Here is the code for my homework assignment. It's long overdue and I didn't do so well on it, but wanted to try to work on my mistakes and problems to actually do better in school; but anyways:

```
  double x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3; // Three points for three vertices. 
                                 // (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  // The program asks the user what the name of the triangle is. Then the program
  // asks the user for the cordinates of each point.
  System.out.print("Enter a three letter name for the triangle: ");
  String triangleName = input.next();
  System.out.print("Coordinates of vertex " + triangleName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + ":");
  x1 = input.nextDouble();
  y1 = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.print("Coordinates of vertex " + triangleName.substring(1,2).toUpperCase() + ":");
  x2 = input.nextDouble();
  y2 = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.print("Coordinates of vertex " + triangleName.substring(2,3).toUpperCase() + ":");
  x3 = input.nextDouble();
  y3 = input.nextDouble();

  double a, b, c; // These values will serve as the three side
                  // lengths between the points.

  // The program displays side lengths in this block.
  System.out.println("--- Side lengths ---");
  a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2-y1, 2));
  System.out.printf(triangleName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
                      + triangleName.substring(1,2).toUpperCase() + ":"
                      + "%.3f", a);
  System.out.println();
  b = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x3-x2, 2) + Math.pow(y3-y2, 2));
  System.out.printf(triangleName.substring(1,2).toUpperCase()
                       + triangleName.substring(2,3).toUpperCase() + ":"
                       + "%.3f", b);
  System.out.println();
  c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x3-x1, 2) + Math.pow(y3-y1, 2));
  System.out.printf(triangleName.substring(2,3).toUpperCase()
                       + triangleName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + ":"
                       + "%.3f", c);
  System.out.println();

  double perimeter, area, xCentroid, yCentroid, inRadius, inArea, semiPerimeter, triangleHeight, triangleBase;

  // The program displays other measures in this block.
  System.out.println("--- Other measures ---");
  perimeter = a + b + c;
  System.out.printf("Perimeter         = " + "%.3f", perimeter);
  System.out.println();
  triangleHeight = y3 - 0.1;
  triangleBase = x2 - x1;
  area = (triangleHeight * triangleBase) / 2;
  System.out.printf("Area              = " + "%.3f", area);
  System.out.println();
  xCentroid = (x1 + x2 + x3) / 3;
  yCentroid = (y1 + y2 + y3) / 3;
  System.out.printf("Centroid          = ( " + "%.3f", xCentroid + ", " + yCentroid + ")");
  System.out.println();
  semiPerimeter = 0.5 * perimeter;
  inRadius = area / semiPerimeter;
  System.out.format("Incircle radius   = " + "%.3f", inRadius);
  System.out.println();
  inArea = Math.PI * Math.pow(inRadius, 2);
  System.out.format("Incircle area     = " + "%.3f", inArea);
  System.out.println();
```

The problem in the code resides on the line for formatting the `xCentroid` and `yCentroid` values respectively. I am getting an error that says `"java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String"`. The math in the program runs fine and works too. I've removed the "%.3f"'s in the statement to see if I get the correct answers, which I do. It's just this format is pissing me off. Please respond, and help. I'll be up for awhile and will be patient.

NEW CODE (FIXED) :

```
  System.out.print("Centroid          = ");
  System.out.print("(");
  System.out.printf("%.3f", xCentroid);
  System.out.print(", ");
  System.out.printf("%.3f", yCentroid);
  System.out.print(")");
  System.out.println();
```

Comment: Please reduce problems to a [mcve] before posting. The majority of the code you've posted is irrelevant, and you haven't given us a complete exmaple we can just copy/paste/compile/run.

Comment: I'm sorry. Will keep in mind for future references! Thanks for telling me. I'm new to this whole StackOverflow thing. Definitely going to be on this more frequent and will be better about posting code.

Answer (score 3):

In this code

```
System.out.printf("Centroid          = ( " + "%.3f", xCentroid + ", " 
                                                        + yCentroid + ")");
```

especially this

```
xCentroid + ", " + yCentroid + ")"
```

is not going to be a number, but a String

I guess what you want is

```
System.out.printf("Centroid          = (%.3f)", xCentroid + yCentroid);
```